# The function of asynchronous data extraction from the archive

Tags: python-3.x, zip, python-asyncio, aiohttp, bytesio

I recently started to study asynchronous python and ran into a problem. Which library to use for working with zip files in async? I am downloading a zip, how can I extract files from it?

```
async def unzip(zip_file_url):
    # zip_file_url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/unscreen/unscreen/uploads/pro_bundle/00e11b66-4b59-4a5b-9ce7-699f599ddb56/IMG_9765.zip'
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        async with client.get(zip_file_url) as resp:
            response = await resp.json() #expected type 'bytes', got 'None' instead 
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))
    return z.extractall("zip/")
```

Comment: Why should the zip file be in a JSON response?

Answer (score 3):

When downloading a zip file you should simply read the response, it's not a JSON request.

```py
async def unzip(zip_file_url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        async with client.get(zip_file_url) as resp:
            response = await resp.read()

    z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response))
    return z.extractall("/zip")
```