# Parallelization of un-bzipping millions of files

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, compression

I have millions of compressed `.bz2` files which I need to uncompressed.

Can uncompression be parallelized ? I have access to the server with many cpu cores for the purpose.

I worked with the following code which is correct but it is extremely slow.

```
import os, glob, bz2

files = glob.glob("/data01/*.bz2")
for fi in files:
fo = fi[:-4]
  with bz2.BZ2File(fi) as fr, open(fo, "wb") as fw:
   shutil.copyfileobj(fr, fw)
```

Comment: Have you considered multithreading?

Comment: There are a lot of Qs and As already on this, and very similar, topics, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281928/easy-parallelisation.  I suggest a little more hunting around.

Comment: Python might not be the right tool: this would be a one-liner in shell with the GNU `parallel` utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multithreading would ideal for this because it's primarily IO-bound.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import glob
import bz2
import shutil

def process(filename):
    with bz2.BZ2File(filename) as fr, open(filename[:-4], "wb") as fw:
        shutil.copyfileobj(fr, fw)

def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as tpe:
        tpe.map(process, glob.glob('/data01/*.bz2'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Actually, if all of the uncompressed files are to be written to the same single device, then "I/O bound" would mean that the speed of the program is limited by the ability to pump the data out to the device. Multi-threading won't help at all with that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code:

```
import pathlib
import itertools
import bz2
import shutil
import multiprocessing as mp


def extract(files):
    for filename in files:
        print(f'Processing {filename}')
        with (bz2.BZ2File(filename) as fr,
              open(filename.stem, 'wb') as fw):
            shutil.copyfileobj(fr, fw)


# For python > 3.8 and < 3.12
def batched(iterable, n):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while (batch := tuple(itertools.islice(it, n))):
        yield batch


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_cpus = mp.cpu_count() - 1  # safe, to leave one free CPU
    files = pathlib.Path('data').glob('*.bz2')
    with mp.Pool(num_cpus) as pool:
        pool.map(extract, batched(files, num_cpus))
```

Instead of creating one process per file, we split the list of files into "num_cpus" batches and process them. As you use all the processors without handover, I leave one processor free.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably looking is to use async.

Refer to this other question that has almost the same context as yours:

[The function of asynchronous data extraction from the archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68368564/the-function-of-asynchronous-data-extraction-from-the-archive).

If your files are already in the server you can skip the part that makes the download and use just the part that opens and extracts the file.

An other alternative is to use async-unzip: https://pypi.org/project/async-unzip/